# How to resolve a database tenant in a multi tenant grails app when the code is run from a scheduled job?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using grails 4.0.3 and the app is multi tenant in database level. I am resolving tenant based on subdomain of the request. The multi tenancy is working well for all the cases except for the scheduled jobs. My understanding is since the scheduled job do not have a request scope the tenant resolver is never called because there is no request to trigger the tenant resolver.
I have a database transactions going on inside scheduled jobs. And these transactions always point to default database.

How can i resolve a tenant from such scenarios where there is no request scope.

My application.yml configuration for tenant resolver is as follows:

```
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: com.pomco.middleware
    gorm:
        reactor:
            # Whether to translate GORM events into Reactor events
            # Disabled by default for performance reasons
            events: false
        multiTenancy:
            mode: DATABASE
            tenantResolverClass: com.pomco.middleware.multitenant.CustomSubDomainTenantResolver
```

And the CustomSubDomainTenantResolver looks like this

```
class CustomSubDomainTenantResolver implements TenantResolver{

    @Override
    Serializable resolveTenantIdentifier() {

        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()
        if(requestAttributes instanceof ServletWebRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((ServletWebRequest) requestAttributes).getRequest()
            def env = DatasourceEnvironment.lookupEnvironmentByHostname(httpServletRequest.getServerName())
            String subDomainId = env?.tenantId
            if( subDomainId) {
                if(!DatabaseProvisioningService.getSourceByTenantId(subDomainId) && subDomainId != 'DEFAULT'){
                    def tenantByUrl = DatabaseProvisioningService.tenantSources.find {it.value == DatabaseProvisioningService.getDbUrlByEnv(env)}
                    if (tenantByUrl){
                        return tenantByUrl.key
                    }
                }
                return subDomainId
            }
            else {
                return ConnectionSource.DEFAULT
            }
        }
        else if(!requestAttributes)
            return ConnectionSource.DEFAULT
        throw new TenantNotFoundException("Tenant could not be resolved outside a web request")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Prabinuperti did you resolve this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Bere Answered my solution. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is using tenant manually by using `withId` closure inside scheduled job.

For example i was not able to get tenant in following Scheduled job.

```
@CurrentTenant
def ExampleService{

// this method runs with required tenant as this is a service method annotated with @CurrentTenant
def methodThatHasTenantScope(){
    ScheduledFuture<?> helperFuture = null
    def result = null

    ScheduledFuture<?> future = ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        // BUT here there is no tenant scope as this is a threaded task which doesn't have a request scope
        // so this job runs with default tenant
        private long count = 0
        @Override
        void run() {
            // job task here runs with default tenant
        }
    }, DELAY, FREQUENCY_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    return result
}
}
```

Now we need to get the tenant id manually in the method `methodThatHasTenantScope` and pass it to the scheduled job method as follows:

```
@CurrentTenant
def ExampleService{

        @Autowired
        HibernateDatastore hibernateDatastore

        def methodThatHasTenantScope(){
            Serializable tenantId = Tenants.currentId(HibernateDatastore)
            log.trace("Current tenant id: $tenantId")
            ScheduledFuture<?> helperFuture = null
            def result = null

            ScheduledFuture<?> future = ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
                private long count = 0
                @Override
                void run() {
                 //here we have tenantId from the scope of the method
                    withId(tenantId){
                        // job task runs with required tenant
                    }
                }
            }, DELAY, FREQUENCY_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            return result
        }
 }
```